# Diferencia entre input list y select

Tags: html

Buenas, ¿cual es la diferencia entre emplear un `input list` o `select`?

A continuación dejo un ejemplo.

```html
<input list="browsers">
   <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">
      <option value="Firefox">
      <option value="Google Chrome">
      <option value="Opera">
      <option value="Safari">
   </datalist>

<select name="Seleccion">
   <option value="Rojo">rojo</option>
   <option value="Verde">verde</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Algunas diferencias:

- Con un `list`/`datalist` puedes introducir valores manualmente que no se ajusten exactamente a los valores sugeridos en el `datalist`, mientras que con un `select` tienes que elegir de los valores de los `option` obligatoriamente.
- `select` es soportado por todos los navegadores, mientras que el soporte para `list`/`datalist` [aunque extendido, aún no está ahí del todo](https://caniuse.com/#search=datalist) y puede dar problemas (especialmente en dispositivos móviles)... Y curiosamente la manera de solucionarlo es tener un `select` dentro del `datalist`.
- Puedes tener múltiples `input list` apuntando al mismo `datalist` sin afectar a la página (crear uno es básicamente automático), mientras que a un `select` debes insertarle todos los `option` para que tenga valores, lo cual puede afectar negativamente al rendimiento.

Y aquí algunas diferencias que van a depender del navegador que uses:

- En Chrome/Firefox, con un `list`/`datalist` puedes buscar los elementos por cualquier parte de la cadena, mientras que con `select` tienes que buscar empezando por el primer carácter de la cadena (por ejemplo, en el `list` puedes escribir una "c" y automáticamente sugerirá "Google Chrome", mientras que en el `select` para seleccionar Chrome habría que empezar con una "g" porque es "Google Chrome"). En IE el comportamiento es el mismo entre `input`/`datalist` y `select`.
- Si hay muchos valores, al desplegar un `select` se mostrarán todos los valores (puede que con un scroll), mientras que con un `list`/`datalist` sólo se mostrarán algunos o ninguno (p.e. Chrome mostrará una lista selecta mientras que Firefox no mostrará nada hasta que no se empiece a escribir).

——-

La principal diferencia es que no son lo mismo: uno es un campo de texto con autocompletado/sugerencias y el otro es una lista de valores fijos. Algunos navegadores los representarán de manera muy similar, pero esa similitud va a depender del navegador que se use (p.e. IE y Chrome muestran los `input list` parecidos a un `select` pero Firefox lo representa como un campo de texto normal hasta que se empieza a escribir).

Answer (score 7):

Según leí (hoy mismo), el `select` te obliga a elegir un valor de la lista, en tanto el `datalist` te permite ingresar un valor que no se halle en la lista (eso a veces conlleva a errores de parte del usuario), ademas  el elemento `datalist`, puede ser utilizado con otros tipos de `input`, no solo texto.

En base a lo que nos dice la `W3C`, esta clase de listas se puede utilizar con tipo `url`, teléfono, color y fecha.
(https://www.lawebera.es/diseno-web-html-5/uso-elemento-datalist.php)